# Android Studio: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1 and com.android.support:design:21.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am getting the following errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:21.0.1
```

I have tried to click the *Install Repository and sync project* for appcompat and after it finished installing and re-syncing, this error shows up again. Now, nothing happens anymore when I click on *Install Repository and sync project* for either appcompat or design.

I have checked other questions and answers including Invalidate Caches/Restart, checked for typo errors, unchecked offline work but none of them worked for me.

My android studio version is 2.2.3.

Screenshot for build.gradle file:

[image]

Screenshot for SDK manager:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Or for the latest use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

Comment: will this cause any problem if my target sdk version is 21?

Comment: use `targetSdkVersion 23` for first one and for latest use `compileSdkVersion 25` and `targetSdkVersion 25`

Comment: but my device is running on sdk version 21 so i have no choice but to use targetsdkversion 21?

Comment: ok....but for release version you should increase the sdk version...to a higher one

Comment: what do you mean by release version? latest version? i think i could not increase the sdk version since i have to use 21 as my device is running on 21

Comment: no release version is the version you release in play store..increase the sdk version will increase the number of devices use you app...did the answer worked?

Comment: i see, the answer worked if i change the targetsdkversion to 23 but what i want is targetsdkversion 21